# Session object with time to live

Tags: jquery, spring, session, spring-mvc

I have made a contact form using Spring MVC which allows to attach files.

Since my form uses AJAX to be submitted, I needed to try a different approach with the attaching of files, so I used jQuery File Upload. As soon as the user selects a file, it gets uploaded straight away, and then since I don't want it to go throguh the disk, I store it on the session and recover it later if the user presses submit.

The problem comes with disposing of this object in the session. If the user submits the form, then I got a sync point where I can remove the object from session thus freeing the memory. But if the user selects a file, then leaves the form without submitting, the file stays in session for its whole lifetime.

I would like to know whether there's a solution to this problem or if this solution could mean any other problems I have not contemplated at all.

Comment: not related to your problem but what happens when there are two tabs with your form open and user selects files on each tab one after another and then submits the form on first tab?

Comment: I added a generated token to the file name so I only recover the desired files